# Get Query String Value in ASP.NET MVC Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. My views use Razor. At the top of my CSHTML file, I have the following:

```
@functions
{
    public static HtmlString IsSelectedCss(string name)
    {
        string selected = ""; // Need to get value of "t" from query string

        HtmlString attribute = new HtmlString("");
        if (selectedTab.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
          attribute = new HtmlString("class=\"active\"");
        }                
        return attribute;
    }
}
```

I need this function to examine the query string. Specifically, I need to get the value of the "t" query string parameter. My challenge is, I cannot seem to figure out how to get access to the QueryString in this function.

How do I get the value of a query string parameter in a Razor function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The query string can be gotten from below.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["t"]
```

Comment: In MVC 6, use `Context.Request.Query["t"]`

Comment: @jbyrd Lucky you ... it won't have a go-live license till nov/dec and won't RTM till early next year. Most orgs won't risk it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your function non-static, since the querystring is part of the request.

You can then write

```
HttpContext.Request.Query["t"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really be doing this in the controller and pushing it through the model.  But if you insist, you can simply use:

```
<%= Request["t"] %>
```

But why not read it in your controller?!